# What's causing the delay in my segues?

Tags: ios, performance, instruments, autolayout, uistoryboardsegue

One of my views freezes up for several seconds when I tap the back button.

In addition, when I tap on one of the items in this view, it shows a popup (custom, not a `UIPopoverController`). This popup appears quite fast, but when I "flip" the popup to see it's back side, the same long delay occurs.

I suspect the reason has something to do with the complexity of the view. As you can see in the screenshot below, it's a collection view, it has a background and some of the subviews are rotated ([UIViewEdgeAntialiasing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) is on).

[image: The white bars that hide the text are not part of the app]

I used the Time Profiler in Instruments to figure out what's going on, but I'm stuck.

[image: The selected time period is when I press the back button and the freeze occurs]

I don't see anything useful unless I deselect "Hide System Libraries":

[image: Include system libraries]

If I look at the method names, I think they are related to auto layout. That suggests that it's trying to render something during the segue. But methods such as `cellForItemAtIndexPath` are not called.

There is also an iPhone version of this app where I don't experience this problem at all. It uses a tableview in stead of a collectionview. It also has a background and rotated pictures.

I took these measurements using the simulator; on my iPad Mini the situation is worse; it can take up to 20 seconds before the animation starts.

**Update - Things I've tried thanks to your answers:**

- turn off `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` : no effect on performance

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be due to the UIViewEdgeAntialiasing flag. It seems that your main view (the one with lots of slightly rotated pictures) have lots of antialiased edges and hence is very taxing on the iPad's GPU. The fact that the drawing performance slows down when your popover is spinning (ie when the background is showing again) gives this some credence.

Try turning it off and see if the performance improves. How does it look like?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that did not improve performance. It just resulted in jagged edges. But I'll try taking out some of the other "special effects" to see if that helps.

Comment: Turns out it was rotation, I'll explain in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation was the bad guy here. Each `UICollectionViewCell` has a `UIView` as a container view and within that is a `UIImageView`. I rotate it like this:

`container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * someRandomFloat);`

Remove that line and everything is snappy.

I use the same technique on the iPhone, but apparently this kind of rotation has less of a performance impact in `UITableViewCell` than in `UICollectionViewCell`.

I tried subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to rotate cell itself in stead of one subview. Unfortunately that causes a similar performance issue.